# Таблицы с прокруткой

Tags: html5

Как можно сделать таблицы с прокруткой?
допустим у меня есть таблица с именем клиента в одном столбце и значениями в остальных 365 столбцах
мне нужно чтобы показывалось постоянно имя, а остальные столбцы были с прокруткой допустим показывает 10 столбцов.такое возможно сделать?

Comment: 365 столбцов - не мало будет??

Comment: это я так))как пример привел..если напишу 10 столбцов наверно написали бы..на 10 столбцов можно и без прокрутки.
я нашел как добавлять скролл. в стилях css нужно блоку добавить событие overflow: scroll две полосы.overflow-x: scroll горизонтальная overflow: scroll вертикальная.
теперь другая проблема..колесиком не прокручивается.кто поможет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Прокрутка колёсиком](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/)

Comment: это только с js нужно делать?

Comment: Горизонтальную прокрутку колёсиком можно настроить только с js.